# can i travel within Schengen area while im holding a D visa with single entry

Tags: schengen, long-stay-visas

Im holding a D visa with single entry from Switzerland. can I travel to other countries in Schengen area? If no, what should I do so as I can go while my visa just valid until this october 9?

Comment: I still cant clealy understand if i can or not. they didnt mention anything related to number of enrey

Comment: @Thanh What's your visa called exactly? D visas usually don't have a specific number of entries or are supposed to be exchanged for a residence permit soon after entering. Unless you have some unusual document that does not allow you to leave Switzerland, travel within the Schengen area should not be a problem.

Comment: @Relaxed Thank you very much. but actually my D visa have single entry T.T do u think it should be better when i travel with the train and bus?

Comment: Train or bus should not make a difference, even a single-entry Schengen visa is OK for air travel *within the area*. But the problem is that D-visa really means “everything else than a regular Schengen short-stay or airport transit visa”, there are literally hundreds of type D visas, potentially with slightly different rules. Almost all of them should allow you to leave Switzerland and travel in the Schengen area but it would be best to know exactly what type of visa you have. Does it say anything on the sticker itself (e.g. under “remarks”)?